# Safari iOS keeps fetching data

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I have a performance issue with Safari on iOS (and Safari when with mobile viewport).
The main issue is images that loads multiple copies and then continuously fetches when tabbing around the site.

Not even sure where to start trouble shooting this issue as it only happens on Safari.

Can it be a broken lazy loading, something wrong with my query, or something else entirely?

I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. 
Right now it sounds like it is a match for SuperUser and not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently a side effect (bug) of using React-Slick-Slide.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).